# Unittest has unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, argparse, python-unittest

I'm running unit tests for my program.py file.  I found an error: `python3 -m unittest: error: unrecognized arguments:`.

I believe the error comes from the `argparse` library I'm using where the target code is expecting some arguments.

Target file: program.py:

```py
import argparse

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Command line program.")
parse.add_argument("--key", type=str,
                   help="Enter key")
parse.add_argument("--output", type=str,
                   help="Path to place results.")
args = parse.parse_args()


def program():
    # Use args here 

def writefile():
    # Uses args and write to file 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program()
```

Test file: program_test.py:

```py
import unittest

import program

class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.argv_list = ["--key", "somefile.txt",
                          "--output", "myresultfile.txt"]

    def test_program_stuff(self):
        # See "Things I've tried" 
        program.writefile(...)
```

Command:

```bash
me@mylinux:myprogram$ env/bin/python3 -m unittest -v program_test.py 

usage: python3 -m unittest [-h] [--key KEY] [--output OUTPUT]
python3 -m unittest: error: unrecognized arguments: -v program_test.py
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Mock the `argparse.Namespace` with `argparse.Namespace(key="key.txt", output="result.txt")`
- Manipulate `sys.args` in test_program_stuff by `sys.args.append(self.argv_list)`

I've looked at solutions to unit testing argparse but none have helped so I'm thinking it may not be the same issue:

- [Python argparse "unrecognized arguments" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712987/python-argparse-unrecognized-arguments-error)
- [argparse fails when called from unittest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325211/argparse-fails-when-called-from-unittest-test)
- [argparse and unittest python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265522/argparse-and-unittest-python)

Comment: -m and -v are for the unittest parser..  But they remain in `sys.argv`, so your parser sees them and complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: I do realize that this is a duplicate of [Pytest unrecognized arguments when importing file with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52450568/8746648), however, that question was unfortunately not answered. It is also a duplicate of [How to call function with argparse arguments in unittests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65886922/8746648), however, he doesn't want to provide arguments and instead wants to call another function defined in the module.*

---

Essentially, the problem can be reduced to the following:

```py
# main.py

import argparse

parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parse.add_argument("--foo", action="store_true")

args = parse.parse_args()
```

and

```py
# tests.py

import main
```

If we run that with `python -m unittest ./tests.py`, we receive the following output:

```
usage: python -m unittest [-h] [--foo FOO]
python -m unittest: error: unrecognized arguments: ./tests.py
```

---

The problem is that if you import something, all the top level code will run during the import. Usually, this isn't a problem because in a library you only really define functions to be used by other programs, however, in your case the `parse.parse_args()` runs.

This can be resolved by guarding this logic similar to what you already did:

```py
import argparse

def main():
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse.add_argument("--foo")

    args = parse.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here, `__name__` will contain the name of the module which would be `"main"` if it is imported or `"__main__"` if it is run directly. Therefore, the `main()` function will not be called during the unit test. [Read more about this here.](https://youtu.be/g_wlZ9IhbTs)

---

However, in your specific case, it seems that you want to test the functionality of the `main()` function (or rather the code that you have in your `main` module.)

There are generally two ways to achieve this:

1. You can simply accept the arguments in `main()`:

   ```py
   import argparse
   import sys

   def main(argv):
       parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
       parse.add_argument("--foo", action="store_true")

       args = parse.parse_args(argv[1:])

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main(sys.argv)
   ```

   Then you are able to provide these arguments in the unit test as well:

   ```py
   import unittest

   import main

   class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
       def test_whatever(self):
           main.main(["main.py", "--foo"])
   ```
2. You can use a mock-framework to change the value of `sys.argv`. In this situation would seem a bit over-engineered. [However, if you are interested, that is answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871265/8746648)

Comment: Interesting, so argparse does some matching between the included sys.argv or included sys.argv[...]?  Since the order doesn't matter when providing sys.argv and .add_argument().  

And thank you!  This works.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. If you are referring to the `argv[1:]` this removes the first entry from the list which is the name of the script, e.g. `"./main.py"`. The whole `parse` object just configures a parser. The parser runs when you exectute `parse_args()` and it looks at `sys.argv` by default or at the provided argument.

Comment: No, I was commenting on the behavior of `parse_args()`.  I mean I can provide my own input list with argv[1:].  Which means objects in `parse` and objects read by `parse_args()` must be matched up.  It makes sense because flags that are passed in through cmdline but not listed in `add_argument` are considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The `parse.parse_args` is outside of a method so will get run when the file is imported by the unittest file. This is why it is complaining that it doesn't have the expected arguments.

A solution is to move the `parse_args` into a function. e.g:

```py
import argparse
import sys


def parse_args(sys_args):
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Command line program.")
    parse.add_argument("--key", type=str,
                       help="Enter key")
    parse.add_argument("--output", type=str,
                       help="Path to place results.")
    return parse.parse_args(sys_args)


def program(key, output):
    # Use args here
    use_key(key)
    writefile(output)


def use_key(key):
    print(f"I have the key: {key}")


def writefile(filename):
    # Uses args and write to file
    print(f"I will write to file: {filename}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parsed_args = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    program(parsed_args.key, parsed_args.output)
```

This then allows things to test individually. e.g:

```py
import io
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import program


class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.argv_list = ["--key", "somefile.txt",
                          "--output", "myresultfile.txt"]

    def test_program_parse(self):
        # See "Things I've tried"
        args = program.parse_args(self.argv_list)
        self.assertEqual("somefile.txt", args.key)
        self.assertEqual("myresultfile.txt", args.output)

    def test_program(self):
        with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new=io.StringIO()) as fake_out:
            program.use_key('val1')
            self.assertEqual('I have the key: val1\n', fake_out.getvalue())

    def test_writefile(self):
        with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new=io.StringIO()) as fake_out:
            program.writefile('junk.txt')
            self.assertEqual('I will write to file: junk.txt\n', fake_out.getvalue())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```